# Full CPU while scrolling UITableView fast up and down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I've been debugging and researching this for a while now, but I can't seem to find the issue. My iOS 10 Swift 3 App basically contains a MapView and a UITableView on the mainScreen. The TableView contains custom UITableViewCells which are based on a few UIViews and UIImages. When I scroll up and down faster, the FPS may drop below 20 on older devices. So I did my research in Instruments and found out, that the CPU is maxing out, while the GPU is around 20%. Most of the threads I read, are describing similiar issues (blending on, offscreen-rendering, and so on) but all those should mainly affect the GPU, if I'm right? Can possibly anyone give me sort of a guideline, in which direction I should do further research?

According to Time Profiler, most of the weight is going into this delegate.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = CustomReuseIdentifier
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    let xyz = dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]

    if let c = cell as? CustomTableViewCell {
        c.delegate = self
        c.xyz = xyz
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Add some code, please. And do you perform any layouting on scroll event?

Comment: Check on Time Profile (Instruments)

Comment: Edited in some more information. @user28434. No, nothing going on in the scroll event.

Comment: Does layout changes while changing content? Are you resizing images? Are you applying masks, corner radius, shadow? Do images have a huge difference in size between the original file and the image view size?

Comment: @Andrea No to all your questions, those were the things i mostly read in the other threads, sadly it's not the case here.

Comment: In your code, the only think I can think of that might be expensive would be `c.xyz = xyz`. Dequeueing a cell from a table should be fast assuming your reuse identifiers are setup properly and `prepareForReuse` isn't doing something expensive. In Time Profiler, you need to drill down further into this method to see exactly what part is taking long.